# Getting Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities while trying to run Selenium Grid in Python using Remote Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, selenium-grid

I am trying to modify my existing Selenium Pytest Page Object Model setup method to make a call to Selenium Grid on Ip "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub".

However when I try to run my test class I am getting a Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities exception. Please find below the code:

conftest.py

```
import options as options
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import DesiredCapabilities
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

selenium_grid_url = "http://192.168.1.8:4444/wd/hub"

@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
    # if browser=='chrome':
    #     driver=webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    # else:
    #     driver=webdriver.Ie()

    dc = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    dc['platform'] = "WIN10"
    dc['version'] = '89'

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


    driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=dc,
                              command_executor=selenium_grid_url, options=options)
    return driver

#
# def pytest_addoption(parser):   # This will get browser value from Command Line
#     parser.addoption("--browser")
#
# @pytest.fixture()
# def browser(request):  # This will return the Browser value to setup method
#     return request.config.getoption("--browser")


##############----------------PyTest HTML Report--------------###########################

# It is hook for Adding Environment info to HTML Report
def pytest_configure(config):
    config._metadata['Project Name'] = 'nop Commerce'
    config._metadata['Module Name'] = 'Customers'
    config._metadata['Tester'] = 'Ishan'

# It is hook for delete/Modify Environment info to HTML Report
@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_metadata(metadata):
    metadata.pop("JAVA_HOME", None)
    metadata.pop("Plugins", None)
```

Page Class : LoginPage.py

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver


class LoginPage:
    textbox_username_id="Email"
    textbox_password_id="Password"
    button_login_xpath="//input[@class='button-1 login-button']"
    link_logout_linktext="Logout"

    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver=driver


    def setUserName(self,username):
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.textbox_username_id).clear()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.textbox_username_id).send_keys(username)

    def setPassword(self,password):
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.textbox_password_id).clear()
        self.driver.find_element_by_id(self.textbox_password_id).send_keys(password)
        time.sleep(10)

    def clickLogin(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.button_login_xpath).click()


    def clickLogout(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_link_text(self.link_logout_linktext).click()
```

My pytest test file:- test_login.py

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from pageObjects.LoginPage import LoginPage
from utilities.readProperties import ReadConfig
from utilities.customLogger import LogGen

class Test_001_Login:
    baseURL = ReadConfig.getApplicationURL()
    username = ReadConfig.getUsername()
    password = ReadConfig.getPassword()
    logger= LogGen.loggen()

    @pytest.mark.sanity
    @pytest.mark.regression
    def test_homePageTitle(self, setup):
        self.logger.info("*******************Test_001_Login***********************")
        self.logger.info("*******************Verifying Home Page Title***********************")

        self.driver = setup
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get(self.baseURL)
        act_title = self.driver.title
        if act_title == "Your store. Login":
            assert True
            self.logger.info('*******************Test Passed - HomePageTitle***********************')
            self.driver.close()

        else:
            self.driver.save_screenshot("D:\\Python Programs\\SeleniumPavanSDET\\NopCommerce\Screenshots\\" + "test_homePageTitle.png")
            self.driver.close()
            self.logger.error('*******************Test Failed - HomePageTitle***********************')
            assert False

    @pytest.mark.sanity
    @pytest.mark.regression
    def test_login(self,setup):
        self.logger.info('*******************Test_001_Login***********************')
        self.logger.info('*******************Verifying Login Test**********************')
        self.driver = setup
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get(self.baseURL)
        self.lp = LoginPage(self.driver)
        self.lp.setUserName(self.username)
        self.lp.setPassword(self.password)
        self.lp.clickLogin()

        act_title = self.driver.title


        if act_title == "Dashboard / nopCommerce administration":
            assert True
            self.logger.info('*******************Test Passed - TestLogin***********************')
            self.driver.close()


        else:
            self.driver.save_screenshot("D:\\Python Programs\\Selenium\\NopCommerce\Screenshots\\"+"test_login.png")
            self.driver.close()
            self.logger.error('*******************Test Failed - TestLogin***********************')
            assert False
```

Exception:-

```
>       driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=dc,
                                  command_executor=selenium_grid_url, options=options)

E       selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Error forwarding the new session cannot find : Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [], extensions: []}, platform: WIN10, version: 89}
E       Stacktrace:
E           at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process (RequestHandler.java:118)
E           at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process (DriverServlet.java:85)
E           at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost (DriverServlet.java:69)
E           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:707)
E           at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service (HttpServlet.java:790)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle (ServletHolder.java:865)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle (ServletHandler.java:535)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:146)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle (SecurityHandler.java:548)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:132)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:257)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle (SessionHandler.java:1595)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle (ScopedHandler.java:255)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle (ContextHandler.java:1340)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:203)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope (ServletHandler.java:473)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope (SessionHandler.java:1564)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope (ScopedHandler.java:201)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope (ContextHandler.java:1242)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle (ScopedHandler.java:144)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle (HandlerWrapper.java:132)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle (Server.java:503)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle (HttpChannel.java:364)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable (HttpConnection.java:260)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded (AbstractConnection.java:305)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable (FillInterest.java:103)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run (ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask (EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce (EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce (EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run (EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run (ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob (QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
E           at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run (QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
E           at java.lang.Thread.run (None:-1)
```

Not sure why this error is coming. I have registered my selenium server as hub and also registered respective nodes.

If anybody could help let me know as to why this error is occuring it would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just replaced that step on mine, works fine for me:

```
selenium_grid_url = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"


@pytest.fixture()
def setup():
    dc = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

    driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=dc,
                              command_executor=selenium_grid_url, options=options)
    return driver
```

by the way, how do you launch selenium-grid, like standalone server?like:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
```

Comment: java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role hub

Comment: @IshanDhaliwal for that purpose, you need to run standalone in another terminal like node

Comment: @IshanDhaliwal or just run standalone with command `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar`

Comment: How will you create a node then?

Comment: @IshanDhaliwal java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://ip-address:4444/grid/register/ . For me it's  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register

Comment: I tried with  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar and I am getting the following error:-
    selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 84

Comment: Not sure where it is looking for chromedriver version

Comment: @IshanDhaliwal have you ever added chromedriver to home path?

Comment: or do you still use such     dc['platform'] = "WIN10"
    dc['version'] = '89'?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230189/discussion-between-vova-and-ishan-dhaliwal).